# lotus notes domino designer text field contains special characters?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula, domino-designer-eclipse

My Lotus notes field allows special characters to be stored in the text box for example `Franco Martínez, José Ramó` this name has special character `í, é, ó` How do i not allow user to paste such character ?

Also, when i create a view can I convert this to a simple string using a method so that it does not contain special characters ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over the input validation of an field you can use a @Fomular to post an failure when the User use one of these characters. Use something like this

[image]

```
@If( @Contains(Field_1;"í");@Failure("no í");@Contains(Field_1;"é");@Failure("no é");@Contains(Field_1;"ó");@Failure("no ó");@Success)
```

If you like to change the characters of exsitings doc, you can use an LS Agent which change characters of the marked documents in a view.

```
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim doccol As NotesDocumentCollection
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim eval As variant



Set doccol =session.Currentdatabase.Unprocesseddocuments
If doccol.Count =0 Then
    MsgBox "please mark docs" ,0, "please mark docs"
    Exit sub
End If

Set doc = doccol.Getfirstdocument()


Do Until doc Is Nothing

    eval = Evaluate({@Replacesubstring(Field_1;"í":"ó":"é";"i":"o":"e")}, doc)
    Call doc.Replaceitemvalue("Field_1", eval)
    Call doc.Save(true,false, true)
    Set doc = doccol.Getnextdocument(doc)
Loop
```

To change the characters in a view column just take

```
@Replacesubstring(columnvalue;"í":"ó":"é";"i":"o":"e")
```

Comment: thanks for your response is it possible to convert it in a view for example i have a view that has one of the column as EMP_NAME so is it possible to just convert the value in the view using a formula ?

Comment: here is the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122306/replacesubstring-doesnt-display-value-as-expected

Comment: yes, I change my answer at the end, please  give my some reputation @dev_marshell08

Comment: There is a slightly impler shortcut, use: @If(@Contains(Field_1;"í":"ó":"é");@Failure("no í"); @Success), since @contains can accept a multivalue parameter.